# Entity Framework: Sql Parameter already contained by another sql collection

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I using entity framework, I have grid with pagination in my page and I have created a sql view for the data source.

I am getting the total records like below,

```
totalRecords = _data.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select count(*) from MyView " + whereClause, parameters.ToArray()).Single();
```

Immediately I am calling the same view to pull the data along with pagesize and page index.

```
totalRecords = _data.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select count(*) from FMRQueue " + whereClause, parameters.ToArray()).Single();
var fmrs = _data.Database.SqlQuery<QueueItemModel>(selectQuery, parameters.ToArray()).Skip(displayStartIndex).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList();
```

It throws `"The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection."` exception.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

A SqlParameter can only be owner by a single collection. You need to manually clone the parameter to add it to a second collection (Your second query).

Here is an extension method "Clone" which use the internal method "Copy" to clone the parameter.

```
var clonedParameters = parameters.Select(x => x.Clone()).ToArray();

public static class Extension
{
    public static SqlParameter Clone(this SqlParameter @this)
    {
        var destination = new SqlParameter();

        var copyToMethod = typeof (SqlParameter).GetMethod("CopyTo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] {typeof (DbParameter)}, null);
        copyToMethod.Invoke(@this, new[] {destination});

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan